# Error connect between PostgreSQL and XAMPP

Tags: postgresql, xampp, codeigniter-3, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

Can someone help me to fixing the problem about connecting PostgreSQL with XAMPP?

The error is :

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Misc has a deprecated constructor in C:\xampp\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php on line 8

I use PostgreSQL version 9.6.2-3 and XAMPP 7.1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (notice) message is based on changes to PHP 7.

So an old way of using a constructor is still in use, is what that message means. It will be ok at the moment, until the support is completely removed in the future. However, I don't believe that should/would cause any connection trouble ?

What is expected is instead of having a class with a constructor like this:

```
<?php
    class foo {
        function foo() {
            echo 'I am the constructor';
        }
    }
?>
```

... would now be expected to look like this:

```
<?php
    class foo {
        function __construct() {
            echo 'I am the constructor';
        }
    }
?>
```

See the first section section of this [PHP 7 deprecation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) info.

You could apply that change yourself, just comment-out the old way, and use the other constructor form.